# Firebase amount of data and performance concerns

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm in the process of creating an application (game) for tablets using Unity and Firebase.

The game consists of different types of exercises the player can do. Each type of exercise has seven levels and every level has four exercises. On an exercise, there's a random question and five different answers, where one of the answers is the right.

See this model for reference:
[image]

One of the major business requirements for this app/game is to be able to create reports based on the answers provided by players. These reports should be created on a monthly basis (based on exercise type):

- Players progress on each answer
- Players average progress on each level
- Players progress on each answer compared to other players on same age
- Players average progress on each level compared to other players on same age
- Players success rate based on time of the day (i.e.: is this players success rate better at 08.00 in the morning?)
- Patterns across players based on gender/age (i.e.: 3 years old male players success rate is good on a given question)
- etc ..

Currently, I'm storing each and every answer a player is making. His/her age, gender, date/time of the attempt, the type of exercise, which level, which exercise, alias of question, alias of provided answer, if the answer was right or wrong and the players unique key.

This ends up in a JSON object looking like this:

```
{
    "exerciseType": "humanBody",
    "level": 1,
    "exercise": 2,
    "questionAlias": "lungsQuestion",
    "answerAlias": "brainAnswer",
    "isCorrect": false,
    "playerKey": "firebasePlayerKey",
    "playerAge": 6,
    "playerGender": "F",
    "answerDateTimeUnix": "unix timestamp here",
    "age_gender_exerciseType_level_exercise": "query field for querying Firebase on multiple parameters.."
    // more query fields to match report criterias?
}
```

My concerns about this, is the amount of data and performance on querys for making the reports/graphs. When there's over 700.000 children playing this game and I'm storing each and every answer provided, that will make for a ***lot*** of data. So much, that I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

So, the question is: will this flat structure be too generic and simply not be performant at all due to the massive amount of real time data stored in Firebase? I could go for a structure, where each answer is stored under a JSON object for the exercise type, i.e.: "humanBody". So I'd "only" need to query data under that particular exercise type rather than querying aginst *all* the answers.

Is there any other approach for this? Or is Firebase simply not the correct tool for the job here?

Any help/hint is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not used Firebase alot but you should be able to shape your JSON into what you want. And what is the amount you are talking by saying "a lot"

Comment: Just made a, rather soft, calculation and the amount is ridiculous. Not sure my calculation is correct, but if 1 player plays the game 3 hours a day for 5 days and provides an answer every 2. second, one player provides approx 27.000 answers a week. Multiply that by 700.000 players and the number is outright insane ;-)

Again: not sure my calculations are correct, though

Comment: If i understood your JSON correctly, you are creating unique branches for each indivual answer, am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The sample JSON I posted is what's stored for each answer a player provides :-)

Comment: As i said before you should be able to change your approach on JSON. What i can think rn is, instead of creating unique branches for each question, just create one branch for one question, and populate it (add child) with users who answered the question.If you check [here](https://pasteboard.co/GJhaq2K.png) , i try to show what i mean.